# Cucumber - Custom HTML Formatter Basics

Tags: format, cucumber

I'm looking to do something relatively simple with a custom cucumber html formatter which is to display the reports where the scenarios are collapsed by default instead of expanded. I have been using this reference as a starting point for implementation:

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/issues/113#issuecomment-1997654

I have done the following:

- Copied the html.rb file to my features/support and renamed it my_html.rb
- Modified the before_steps method to use @builder << ''
- Altered the class definition within the file from Html to MyHtml
- Attempted to call the formatter using 'cucumber -d -f Cucumber::Formatter:MyHtml'

but I get

```
no such file to load -- cucumber:formatter:my_html
Error creating formatter: Cucumber:Formatter:MyHtml (LoadError)
```

so I try and specify the file itself but get the same error.

I'm relatively new to cucumber and object orientation so my simple question is - how do I get this to work?

I believe my environment is Ok I have an env.rb and hooks.rb file in the same features/support directory that are picked up ok.

Also, once I get it to see where the file is, do I need to modify the require statements as those (relative) references don't exist under my features/support directory..

Thanks in advance

Comment: As a troubleshooting step, you can run cucumber with the `-v` switch to display exactly which code files are getting loaded, so you can check that it is finding your formatter.  Also posting some more code from your custom formatter would help.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to missing a colon, i.e. instead of

```
cucumber -d -f Cucumber::Formatter:MyHtml
```

try

```
cucumber -d -f Cucumber::Formatter::MyHtml
```

Comment: Ah, thanks for that. I've managed to get it working now. Had to copy a couple of supplementary files (cucumber.css and a js file) but worked ok after that.

Comment: @user1158166 i am having the same error how were you able to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

A simple hack to collapse the HTML report uses following command after the report is generated.

```
sed -e "s/<\/script><\/div><\/body><\/html>/\$(function(){\$('.keyword').click();});<\/script><\/div><\/body><\/html>/g" report.html > report2.html
```

This is worked for me.